# Remove Jar File Name From URL in java Hosting

Tags: jsp, hosting

i have hosted my Latest Project done in JSP.

as i have uploaded my XYZ.Jar for hosting

this XYZ appears as an extension in my Url

eg. MydomainName.com/XYZ

how do i remove this jar file name from my url